# Finding the 2 smallest integers from a set of 3

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, integer

I'm using the following to discover the largest integer from 3 values.

```
<?php
$a = 100;
$b = 200;
$c = -300;
$max = max($a,$b,$c);
foreach( array('a','b','c') as $v) {
    if ($$v == $max) {
        echo "\$$v is $max and therefore the largest";
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

This works perfectly with the output: **$b is 200 and therefore the largest**

However, I would now like to also output the 2 smallest integers from the 3.

So as well as showing the 1 largest, it would also output the 2 others.

Can someone show me how I can achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate Matt answer :

```
$list = array(2, 3, 1);
sort($list);

echo "Largest element : ".$list[count($list)-1]."\n";
echo "Two smallest elements :";

for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
    echo $list[$i]." ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. put the three integers in a list
2. [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) the list
3. take the first two elements -> these are the two smallest
4. the last element is the largest

Comment: Thanks for this, Matt. Appreciate the reply. I've got this so far `$nums = array(100,200,-300);
sort($nums);` how do I now take the first 2 elements?

Comment: @mcgarriers -- I would just do `$first = $nums[0]; $second = $nums[1];` for a quick-n-dirty solution.  I assume there's a function that gets a sublist for you, but I'm not a PHP expert so I don't know what it would be.  EDIT:  `array_slice` does this.

Comment: Thanks. Managed with: `$nums = array(100,200,-300);
sort($nums);
foreach ($nums as $key => $val) {
    echo "nums[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n<br />";
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$nums = array(100,200,-300); 
sort($nums);
$twoSmallest = array_slice($sorted,0,2);
$largest = array_slice($sorted,-1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the rest of the "sort it!" crowd. Here's a complete example where the name of the variables involved are kept, so the result is like the one in your example:

```
function var_cmp($_a, $_b) {
  global $$_a, $$_b;
  return $$_b - $$_a;
}

$a = 100;
$b = 200;
$c = -300;
$result = array('a', 'b', 'c');
usort($result, 'var_cmp');
printf('$%s is %d and largest, followed by $%s = %d and $%s = %d',
       $result[0], ${$result[0]},
       $result[1], ${$result[1]},
       $result[2], ${$result[2]});
```